# How to add metadata (source of the dataset) to a file (dataset)?

Tags: file-management, metadata, cross-platform, statistics

I usually have to download datasets from websites through a point-and-click system that is difficult to replicate in a Makefile. In these cases, I want to include as much metadata about how I downloaded these files as possible to ensure reproducibility.

How do this that allows the metadata to be attached to all file types (e.g. .Rdata, .dta, .csv, etc.) and available across platform (i.e. Windows, Linux, Mac OS)?

Alternatively, if there is a better way to keep the information about data sources with the data, it'd be useful to know.